# Difference between node_gets and vnode_gets in Riak

Tags: riak, riak-kv

Can anyone please tell me the difference the following metrics in Riak:
1. node_gets vs vnode_gets
2. node_puts vs vnode_puts

As per the documentation, *node_gets* is the number of gets co-ordinated by a node in the Riak cluster in the last 60 seconds, whereas vnode_gets is the number of gets co-ordinated by *vnodes* on a particular node. Since vnodes are responsible for managing the partitions and data in a Riak cluster, I am guessing that the node_gets should be a subset of vnode_gets.

If I have to figure out the number of get/put on the cluster by different clients, which among *node_gets/vnode_gets* and *node_puts/vnode_puts* should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the client sends a `get` it goes to a single node that coordinates the get.  The `node_gets` stat at that node gets incremented.

The node hashes the requested key, looks up the has in the ring, and gets the `n_val`(default 3) vnodes that should hold the value.  It then forwards the request to the node that owns each of those vnodes.  The `vnode_gets` stat at each of those nodes is then updated.

So each get from the client should equate to 1 node_get and n_val vnode_gets.

Comment: Great. Thanks for explaining in detail!